# boot lost after Windows clonezilla disk to disk

Tags: windows-10, boot

I ran Clonezilla disk to disk cloning to shift my PC from HDD to SSD. I forgot to downsize the partition on the source drive (750GB) to the destination drive (240GB). During the clone I must've selected the 'clone the boot loader' option at the end. But the clone failed. Now I have removed the SSD and cannot boot back to the original drive.

I tried System Recovery Options on a Windows 10 installation media and it shows a "Windows 10" OS with partition size of 0 MB in (Unknown) Local Disk. Startup Repair fails with "CorruptBootConfigData".

I have tried the `bootrec /rebuildbcd` `bootrec /fixmbr` `bootrec /fixboot` commands but they do nothing and I get an error "The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors" on boot.

I have 4 partitions on this drive (from HP Pavilion Desktop):

```
#   Type       Ltr   Size   Label        Info
1   Primary    C    100MB   SYSTEM  
2   Primary    D    687GB   HP
3   Recovery   E    450MB   FACTORY_IMA
4   Primary    F     10GB                Hidden
```

None of the volumes have Boot or System under Info.

The OS was upgraded from W7 to W10 with the free upgrade from Microsoft so I have no W10 installation recovery media.

When I try `detail disk` using `diskpart` it tells me `Boot Disk : No`

How do I make this disk/system boot again?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the issue:

I booted into recovery console command prompt and made partition 1 (labelled "SYSTEM") active using `diskpart` but got the new error "A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed". The HDD and DVD player were connected, accessible, and the SSD was no longer connected.

At this point the new error implied that I couldn't find the right partition.

I then went back into the recovery console command prompt and viewed the BCD via `bcdedit`. Viewing the BCD showed several entries where `device` and `osdevice` were "unknown". I then used the `bcdedit` commands to set the "device" "osdevice" for {default} and other entries to D: partition where Windows was, e.g. `bcdedit /set {default} device partition=D:` or `bcdedit /set {default} device partition=D:`.

If I recall the full command may have included store location, but I'm not sure if that was required, e.g. `bcdedit /store c:\boot\BCD /set {default} device partition=D:`